# iOS Custom View Controller

Tags: ios

I am trying to have the ability to switch views in and out. The screens are generated on the fly and there may be anywhere from 30-100 of them that will be presented sequentially. A NavigationController may work, but I may be creating a hundred or so screens so I am worried it will run out of memory if I push that many views. Maybe this could work if I only ever added one screen at a time to the NavigationController, and when a new one is added remove all screens and then add the new one. But this may cause strange animations.

I tried creating a custom View Switcher that could load each of the views on the fly following the chapter 6 example in the apress book. The problem is that on rotations the events do not make it to the View Controller for the currently visible view. So it ends up doing weird things on screen rotations.

Another approach that I am thinking may work is to use a tab bar controller and make the tabs invisible. Then I can just use tabs 1 and 2 to hold the current view, and the last view and ping pong back and forth. Then memory is not as much of an issue as using a NavigationController.

Does anyone have any other ideas? I feel like there should be an easier way to do this that I am just not seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating a singleton "ScreenManager" that loads, adds and removes your views on your root view controller? This way you can make sure that the view hierarchy isn't convoluted and out of your control. It's also a good idea design-wise and should be very easy and efficient with memory management.